# Excel Evaluate Text as Logical

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to evaluate a logical expression by concatenating the operands and operator. Is there a formula to convert from text to logical in Excel 2016, similar to how `VALUE()` converts from text to number? I'm looking to a solution for this so I can dynamically change the condition without changing the actual Excel formula. I've searched and read through the Excel function descriptions, but nothing is jumping out as a solution.

```
'The operands and operator
A1: 1
A2: >
A3: 0

'Concatenation
B4: =CONCAT(A1:A3) 'This evaluates to 1>0
B5: =A1&A2&A3 'This also evaluates to 1>0

'Some checks
C4: =ISTEXT(B4) 'This evaluates to TRUE.
C5: =ISTEXT(B5) 'This also evaluates to TRUE
D4: =ISLOGICAL(B4) 'This evaluates to FALSE
D5: =ISLOGICAL(B5) 'This also evaluates to FALSE

'Vain attempts
E4: =AND(B4,TRUE) 'This ALWAYS is TRUE, even when my desired output is FALSE
E5: =OR(B5) 'This spits out a #VALUE! error
```

Since I'm looking for something dynamic, I want to avoid a solution such as
`=IF(A2=">",A1>A3,FALSE)`. I also would prefer to avoid a UDF but am willing to go that route if no built in function exists to convert a logical expression in text and evaluate it as logical.

Comment: If you do decide to got the UDF route, this will do it 
`Function Eval(r As Range) As Variant
    Eval = r.Worksheet.Evaluate(r.Value)
End Function`

Comment: No, no built in function exists.  UDF is the best route.

Comment: +1 @chrisneilsen. I had begun a UDF but was doing it the hard way. Your elegant one-liner works perfectly. I used it in my answer below which can accept an expression or an Excel range as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a UDF calling Evaluate, that can handle either a Range or Variant/String input, try the following:

```
Function L(exp As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vExp As Variant

    vExp = exp
    L = Application.Evaluate(vExp)
End Function
```

Why does it work?

The line `vExp = exp` does the magic.  If `exp` is a Range then the assigment uses the default `.Value` property and copies as a Variant/String (because we are not using `Set`).  If it's a Variant/String, then it's a straight copy.

It does have the downside of using `Application.Evaluate` (downside as explained
[here](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/) )

---

A version to also handle the possibility of being called from VBA, try

```
Function L(exp As Variant) As Variant
    If TypeName(exp) = "Range" Then
        L = exp.Worksheet.Evaluate(exp.Value)
    Else
        If IsError(Application.Caller) Then
            'Calls from VBA are hanbled here.
            ' Note: Best to fully qualify any range references in exp
            ' to avoid unexpected references to the active sheet
            L = ActiveSheet.Evaluate(exp)
        Else
            L = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Evaluate(exp)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments that no built-in function takes care of this, I made a user-defined function ("UDF") called L() for *logical*, taking after the built-in functions N() and T() which are for *numbers* and *text*.

```
Function L(exp As Variant) As Variant

Dim limit As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

'Set an upper limit to how many cycles the loop may run
limit = 1000

'Assuming the possibility of nested functions, loop until the expression resolves to logical or to an error or until the loop limit has been reached
Do
    exp = [exp] 'This avoids Error 2015 if exp is a Range reference. Comment if there's a better way!
    exp = Application.Evaluate(exp) 'Evaluate the expression
    counter = counter + 1 'Increment the loop counter
Loop Until Application.IsLogical(exp) Or Application.IsError(exp) Or counter >= limit 

'Return the evaluated expression
L = exp

End Function
```

This function works even when I throw some silly things its way like `=L(TRUE)` or `=L(CONCAT(A1:A2)&A3)` or even `=l(CONCAT(A1:A2)&"""foo""")`. But it does not throw errors in cases where it probably should, such as `=l(123)` or `=l("123")`. In these cases, thank goodness for the counter limit because `123` and `"123"` will never evaluate to a logical or an error.

Comment: I really don't see the need for a loop.  Remember that if the parameter you are passing to `L` is a formula (like your examples) that formula is evaluated and th result passed to the UDF.  Can uou give any examples that will execute the loop more than once?

Comment: In my comment I used the Worksheet version of Evaluate.  [See this link for why](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/)

Comment: Re use of `exp=[exp]`: A better way is `If TypeName(exp) = "Range" Then
    exp = Application.Evaluate(exp.Value)
Else
    exp = Application.Evaluate(exp)
End If `

Comment: @chrisneilsen you are right on all accounts. I don't think I have a clear understanding of what evaluate does. I'll have to read up on that and your link re evaluate. Should I post amended code as an update?

Comment: @chrisneilsen after reading up on Evaluate, I wondered if `If TypeName(exp) = "Range" Then exp = exp.Worksheet.Evaluate(exp.Value) Else exp = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Evaluate(exp) End If` was a safe way to go or if Application.Caller had any dangers.

Comment: As I feared, Application.Caller will error out (Run-time '424' Object required) when L is run from a sub such as `Sub foo() MsgBox L("1>0") End Sub`.